# specify field name instead of "value"

Tags: joi

I have to validate value by value instead of passing in a whole schema for multiple values. Based on the docs for single value validation from here

https://hapi.dev/module/joi/

and this sample code

```
const validator: AnySchema = Joi.string().valid('foo', 'bar').required();
const validationResult: ValidationResult = validator.validate('invalid');
const validationError: ValidationError = validationResult.error;

if (validationError) {
    throw validationError;
}
```

The code will throw an error with the following error message

> ValidationError: "value" must be one of [foo, bar]

Is there an easy way I can replace `"value"` with a specific name? So when I want to validate **environment** the error message could be

> ValidationError: "environment" must be one of [development, production,
>   test]

or is that only possible when validating multiple values at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [`any.label(name)`](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#anylabelname) method that you can use and set a custom label that will be displayed in error messages as well:

> **[any.label(name)](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#anylabelname)**
>
> Overrides the key name in error messages.
>
> - `name` - the name of the key.
>
> ```
> const schema = {
>     first_name: Joi.string().label('First Name')
> };
> ```

You can simply do:

```ts
const validator: AnySchema = Joi
  .string()
  .label('Foo/Bar') // Change tha label using label method
  .valid('foo', 'bar')
  .required();

const validationResult: ValidationResult = validator.validate('invalid');
const validationError: ValidationError = validationResult.error;

if (validationError) {
    throw validationError;
}
```

will output:

```js
ValidationError: "Foo/Bar" must be one of [foo, bar]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help :) unfortunately I can grant you the bounty in 14 hours ..

Comment: @Question3r you're welcome. Don't worry about the bounty, it gets rewared to the accepted answer when it expires so it's OK even if you forget about it ;-)